# Check ember app with google closure

Tags: javascript, ember.js, google-closure-compiler

I would like to check an ember app with the google closure compiler (I'm not interested in minimizing).

I call the compiler like this:

```
java -jar compiler-latest/compiler.jar --language_in=ECMASCRIPT6 
    --language_out=ES5 --checks-only  --manage_closure_dependencies app
```

But that setting seems to skip JSDOC based type checking, since the following code does not trigger any error:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
   /**
    * Returns the ID of the last item.
    * @return {number} The ID.
    */
    test: function() {
      return "a";
   }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a valid code snippet that demonstrates the problem?